# Deleting namespace was stuck at "Terminating" State

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, minikube, terminate

I want to delete a namespace created in kubernetes.
Command i executed:

**kubectl delete namespaces devops-ui**

But the process is taking too long (~20mins) and counting.

On checking the minikube dashboard a pod is still there which is not getting deleted, it is in terminating state.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please delete the pods first using below command

```
kubectl delete pod  pod_name_here --grace-period=0 --force --namespace devops-ui
```

now delete the namespace

```
kubectl delete namespaces devops-ui
```

Answer (score 2):

1. when you delete a namespace, it triggers deleting all the entities within that namespace
2. you can run "kubectl get all -n namespace-name" and see the status of all the components within the namespace
3. Ideally it is preferable to wait for all the pods to be cleanly deleted (instead of forcing the pod deletion with --grace-period=0 : this only deletes the etcd record for the pod - but the corresponding containers could be running)

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/

Answer (score 1):

Some CRD's have finalizers and this will prevent a namespace from terminating

Example followed from here
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60807#issuecomment-408599873

```
@ManifoldFR , I had the same issue as yours and I managed to make it work by making an API call with json file .
kubectl get namespace annoying-namespace-to-delete -o json > tmp.json
then edit tmp.json and remove"kubernetes"

curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @tmp.json https://kubernetes-cluster-ip/api/v1/namespaces/annoying-namespace-to-delete/finalize
```

Note - use this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/ - if you are running test cluster  and need to get cluster-api access

In my case it threw up the resources holding (in default namespaces)

```
    {
        "type": "NamespaceContentRemaining",
        "status": "True",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-10-09T09:35:11Z",
        "reason": "SomeResourcesRemain",
        "message": "Some resources are remaining: cephblockpools.ceph.rook.io has 2 resource instances, cephclusters.ceph.rook.io has 1 resource instances"
      },
      {
        "type": "NamespaceFinalizersRemaining",
        "status": "True",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-10-09T09:35:11Z",
        "reason": "SomeFinalizersRemain",
        "message": "Some content in the namespace has finalizers remaining: cephblockpool.ceph.rook.io in 2 resource instances, cephcluster.ceph.rook.io in 1 resource instances"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: You're right in the case of the CRDs some finalizers will **prevent** the namespace deletion and stuck at terminating. One of the methods to delete that namespace is using this approach. I have found this [article](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/the-hidden-dangers-of-terminating-namespaces) quite helpful in knowing the full context and if someone is interested to safely remove the resources.