# `kubectl delete service` gets stuck in 'Terminating' state

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to delete a service I wrote & deployed to Azure Kubernetes Service (along with required Dask components that accompany it), and when I run `kubectl delete -f my_manifest.yml`, my service gets stuck in the Terminating state. The console tells me that it was deleted, but the command hangs:

```
> kubectl delete -f my-manifest.yaml
service "dask-scheduler" deleted
deployment.apps "dask-scheduler" deleted
deployment.apps "dask-worker" deleted
service "my-service" deleted
deployment.apps "my-deployment" deleted
```

I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> this command. When I check my services, Dask has been successfully deleted, but my custom service hasn't. If I try to manually delete it, it similarly hangs/fails:

```
> kubectl get services
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes          ClusterIP      x.x.x.x      <none>        443/TCP                      18h
my-service          LoadBalancer   x.x.x.x      x.x.x.x       80:30786/TCP,443:31934/TCP   18h

> kubectl delete service my-service
service "my-service" deleted
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240272/deleting-namespace-was-stuck-at-terminating-state) says to delete the pods first, but all my pods are deleted (`kubectl get pods` returns nothing). There's also [this closed K8s issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66110) that says `--wait=false` might fix foreground cascade deletion, but this doesn't work and doesn't seem to be the issue here anyway (as the pods themselves have already been deleted).

I assume that I can completely wipe out my AKS cluster and re-create, but that's an option of last resort here. I don't know whether it's relevant, but my service is using [the `azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"` annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#create-an-internal-load-balancer) for the service, and I have a webapp deployed to my VNet that uses this service.

Is there any other way to force shutdown this service?

Comment: post the output of `kubectl describe service my-service`. you are probably having an issue with LB deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @4c74356b41's suggestion of looking at `kubectl describe service my-service` (which I hadn't considered for some reason), I saw this warning:

> Code="LinkedAuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/write' on scope '/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes-internal'; however, it does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnet>/subnets/<subnet>' or the linked scope(s) are invalid.

(The client and object id GUIDs are the same value.)

This indicated that it's not exactly a Kubernetes issue, but moreso permissions within the Azure ecosystem. I looked through the portal and didn't find that GUID in any of my users, groups, or apps, so I'm not sure what it's referring to. However, I granted the `Owner` role to this client id, and after a few minutes, the service deleted.

```
az role assignment create `
    --role Owner `
    --assignee xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue with a svc not connecting to the pod cause the pod was already deleted:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='scv-name-not-shown-because-prod.namespace-prod', port=7999): Max retries exceeded with url: 
my-url-not-shown-because-prod (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7faee4b112b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

I was able to solve this with the patch command:

```
kubectl patch service scv-name-not-shown-because-prod -n namespace-prod -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

I think the service went into some illegal state and was not able to ricover

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, a follow-up to [Cr4zyTun4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74303452/1518121), in which finalizers are patched to null to allow deletion to complete.

I needed a slightly different syntax on the Windows CLI:

```
kubectl patch service svc-name -n namespace  -p "{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}"
```

When I used the version enclosed with ' symbol, Windows threw an error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what Windows CLI means? (PS/Powershell, CMD/Command Prompt, WSL/Windows Subsystem for Linux Bash) Windows 11's Windows Terminal will let you use any of those.

Comment: @neoakris In my case, Windows Server 2019, CMD prompt.